# rake db:seed NameError: uninitialized constant Exercice in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a Course app to learn language. I migrated numerous models as Course, Chapter and Item (using acts_as-active_record gem). Items is **actable** and Lesson, Exercise and Exam are **act_as** Item.
I create a seed like this :

```
rails = Course.create(name: "Ruby On Rails")

models = rails.chapters.create(name: "Models")

# first item is a lesson
models.items << Lesson.create(name: "What is Active Record?", content: "Lesson content here")

# then 2 exos
models.items << Exercise.create(name: "The Active Record pattern", content: "Exo about active record pattern")
models.items << Exercise.create(name: "Object Relational Mapping", content: "Exo about ORM")
models.items << Exercise.create(name: "Active Record as an ORM Framework", content: "Exo about ORM")

# a second lesson
models.items << Lesson.create(name: "Convention over Configuration in Active Record", content: "Lesson content here")

# 3 exos
models.items << Exercise.create(name: "Naming Conventions", content: "Exo about naming convention")
models.items << Exercise.create(name: "Schema Conventions", content: "Exo about schema convention")

# a summary lesson
models.items << Lesson.create(name: "Model summary", content: "Lesson content here")

# an exam
models.items << Exam.create(name: "Rails Models exam", content: "Exam content here")


# You can go to next course with : next_item = Course.first.chapters.first.items.first.lower_item
# Then go to next chapter with: next_item.chapter.lower_item
```

But in my rails console rake db:seed I have an error which notifies 
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Exercice
../db/seeds.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
-e:1:in`'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed

I really don't know what is the error. 
Maybe Is there a relation with acts_as-active_record?

Here are the models :

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base 
has_many :chapters, -> { order(position: :asc) } 
validates_presence_of :title 
end 

class Chapter < ActiveRecord::Base 
acts_as_list scope: :course 
belongs_to :course 
has_many :items, -> { order(position: :asc) } 
validates_presence_of :title 
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base 
actable 
belongs_to :chapter 
acts_as_list scope: :chapter 
validates_presence_of :title 
end 

class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base 
acts_as :item 
end 

class Exercise < ActiveRecord::Base 
acts_as :item 
end



class Exam < ActiveRecord::Base 
 acts_as :item 
end
```

The whole seed is here.

Comment: Can you put your model declarations and relationships?

Comment: It's probably unrelated but Exercise is spelled incorrectly in your example.

Comment: Can you also paste the whole `db/seeds.rb` file?

Comment: The whole db/seeds.rb is above.

Comment: Please look above @pjam

Comment: By the error @BaptisteBecmeur you are misspelling Exercise. Your model is declared as "Exercise" and you are using in seeds  Exercice, this by looking at your error " Exercice ../db/seeds.rb:19:i"

Comment: I gonna try @Randall Valenciano

Comment: @RandallValenciano it done only this line => Running via Spring preloader in process 8507

Comment: @BaptisteBecmeur no more output at the terminal??

Comment: no more do you know why? @RandallValenciano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `Exercice` and `Exercise` do not match.

```
models.items << Exercice.create(name: "The Active Record pattern", content: "Exo about active record pattern")

class Exercise < ActiveRecord::Base 
  acts_as :item 
end
```

Comment: it works! Tahnk you. I wanna destroy the seed. Do you know how to do?

Comment: Please accept the answer if the answer is correct. I am not sure what you mean by destroying the seed, but you can simply reset the database by typing ``rake db:drop`` then ``rake db:migrate`` in your console (assuming that you are using sqlite/postgres)

Comment: Yes but I want just added a button delete or method to destroy it on my show#view. I think I am not clear with my questions, sorry.